# How to call REST API to external server from Jenkins

Tags: rest, jenkins

I want to implement that when a build is performed in Jenkins, call my server Rest API.

Calling Jenkins REST API on my server to perform Build was successful.

[image]

How to call external server REST API in Jenkins? is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. One option is, you can use something like the [HTTP Request Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/). Then in your [Post](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) step, you can do the HTTP request like below.

```
def response = httpRequest 'https://your_host/something'
```

Another option is to simply use something like `curl` to send an HTTP request. You can execute your `curl` command within a `sh` block.

```
sh "curl -vk https://your_host/something"
```

Comment: There's also [REST List Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rest-list-parameter/) if you want to invoke as a list option for "Build with Parameters" /parameterized build.

Comment: thanks for answering! I made it.

I have another qeustion.

when finish build, i want to call rest api to my own server. 
but there is no HTTP Request in Jenkins Post-build action..

any ideas ?

@ycr